# how to get the name of active datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, refresh

Good day guys, I have 5 datagridview which is bind in 5 different binding source.

After my edit function I want to refresh the datagrid or the dataset but I cant get the name of the active datagridview.

what i wanted to do after the edit is this :

```
(Active Datagridview)..DataSource = typeof(List); 

(Active Datagridview).DataSource = dataset.Tables["your table"];
```

this is my way to refresh the data in datagridview, I'll remove the datasource of datagrid view and set again the datasource.

anyone there can help me,.. thanks in advace :)

Comment: what do you mean by "Active DataGridView"? currently focused? currently being edited?

Comment: I think datagrid that is currently focused because i have sub in each datagridview cell double click that will show the edit form then i want to get the name of datagrid where I did the double click..

Comment: so you are trying to call the active grid view in your edit form? i think you could pass a reference of the gridview (when you showing the edit form in the double click event, you should know it already) to the edit form

Comment: I only have one edit form that can view all the data from the different datagridview. what I did is Im getting the primary key of each data in the different datagridview when it is doubled click then fill my dataset in editform..

Comment: yes, correct. when you passing the data Id into your edit form, you actually already know which DataGridView the data (row/object) is from since you handled the click event, right? at that point, you already know the gridview, why not pass a reference of it to wherever you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

yourDatagridview.Name

Comment: @Juan Filipe, question was "_how to get the name of active datagridview_", not how update my datagridview... isn't? :)

Comment: How you know that `yourDatagridview` is Active datagridview? :)

Comment: he can use the sender if it is in one of the datagridview's events.. basically, he just wants to know the name of the datagridview.. i assume he already knows where to put it but do not know how to get the name as he stated in the question..

Answer (score -1):

In your event handler `datagridview_DoubleClick` you can get a reference to datagridview where was double clicked. So you can have only one handler for all 5 datagridviews.
In this handler you can put reference of `DataGridView` to your Edit form(before create constructor of Edit form with parameter of DataGridView) or get only a name of DatagridView as you was asked

```
private sub datagridview_DoubleClick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handle datagridview1.DoubleClick,
                                                                       datagridview2.DoubleClick,
                                                                       datagridview3.DoubleClick,                                                                              
                                                                       datagridview4.DoubleClick,
                                                                       datagridview5.DoubleClick
    Dim dgvClicked as DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    dim frmEdit as FormEdit = New FormEdit(dgvClicked)
    frmEdit.ShowDialog()
    ....

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the Answer!,.. but I cant Refresh the binding source of each datagridview,.. I already tried dgvClicked.bindingsource = nothing then after that i assigned again its datasource but the data in datarid is not updated but on the database its alredy updated.. tnx AGAIN!,..

Comment: Try `dgvClicked.DataSource = updatedDataTable` check if `updatedDataTable` keep really updated data...

Comment: this answer does not solve his 'real' question.. i can see why he voted for my answer.. just see the title and the first part of his question.. you'll see he's only looking for the name..

Comment: @E-rGabrielDoronila, your answer when he accept was "_update your datatable first_". About name you added after my comment. And in question he want to do: `(ActiveDataGridView).DataSource = DataTable`. Thats why my question was accepted first.